# /etc/exports configuration for nfs

Tags: linux, networking, mount, nfs

I'd like to setup nfs between server and client.
So I modified server PC /etc/exports like below.

`/directory 193.101.102.0/255.255.255.0(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)`

I expected client which ip is '193.101.102.211' can mount but does not.
It failed and message is
`mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting 193.101.102.211:/directory`

Do I have to change configuration ?

Comment: Does the entry show up in `exportfs -v`? Do you have any _other_ exports entries? In particular, do you happen to have an entry with "fsid=0" or "fsid=root" somewhere in your exports?

Comment: We need more info about the definition of the share and the client permissions and mount command. Check also your firewall.

Comment: @user1686 I can see only '/directory 193.101.102.0/255.255.255.0(sync,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)'

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your comment but firewall does not installed nfs server side.

Comment: We still need more information.

Comment: Do you have the rpc.mountd (or equivalent nfsv4.exportd) process running?

Comment: @user1686 nfsv4.0-svc is running

Comment: @harrymc Could you let me know which information you need for solution? I can provide as much as you need.

Comment: @HyunyoungGo: Specifically, is rpc.mountd running? (And if it's running, did it log anything about the rejection?)

Comment: @user1686 rpc.mountd is not running. When I try rpc.mountd -F, it says 'rpc.mountd: Could not make a socket: (97) Address family not supported by protocol'

Comment: Can you `strace` it and figure out which socket call is the one that fails with EAFNOSUPPORT?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using sshfs.

I had one more problem which have to mount a directory that already mounted from another PC. Fortunately, sshfs can do it.

Answer (score 1):

First the file you should edit is `/etc/exports` not `/etc/exportfs`.

Second you should have the directory name as first symbols in the line:

```
/test 193.201.9.0/255.255.255.0(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Edit the file and the execute (as root)

```
exportfs -r
```

Comment: Thank you, I followed your description but still not work.

Comment: @HyunyoungGo, check if your NFS server is started, check firewall

Comment: I can see following process working on.
nfsiod, 
/usr/sbin/nfsdcld, 
nfsd4_callback, 
nfsd, 
nfsv4.0-svc

--------------
Could you let me know which one is server service..?
And the firewall is not install.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux NFS kernel server relies on rpc.mountd (aka nfsv4.exportd) to confirm access to every mount request. (The mountd daemon really performs two tasks – it serves the RPC "MOUNT" protocol for NFSv2/v3 *and* performs server-side access checking for NFSv4, so it's still required even if the "MOUNT" protocol no longer exists in NFSv4.) If rpc.mountd is not running, all access checks will automatically fail.